# Enter the URL after prompt in imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want to run iMacros with a url set from prompt instead of a hardcoded url. I've tried this code but it always fails with an error:

> ```
> http://__undefined__/
> ```

My macro:

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
var URLN = prompt("Please enter your URL: ");
var CHOICE = prompt("Please enter your Choice: ");
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAB T=2" + "\n";
macro +=  "URL GOTO={{!URLN}}" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:{{!CHOICE}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro)
```

Any ideas how to get the URL from prompt?

Comment: You simply need to set variables by means of the [`iimSet()` function](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimSet).

Comment: thanks its working <3 <3